# Why is the Button not Rendered?

Tags: reactjs

I'm looking at this React application: https://github.com/eroepken/jeopardy-js

And I cannot figure out how the button (`className={clue-card__value ${valueClass}}`) which shows the card value is not rendered after it is clicked. I would have thought there would have been some state to hold the value of clicked true/false but there is not. I didn't see anything in the CSS either.

What am I missing?

```
import React from 'react';

export default class ClueCard extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      cardText: props.children,
      clueIsShowing: false,
      showAnswerLink: false,
      answerIsShowing: false
    };

    this.showClue = this.showClue.bind(this);
    this.hideClue = this.hideClue.bind(this);
    this.showAnswerLink = this.showAnswerLink.bind(this);
    this.toggleAnswer = this.toggleAnswer.bind(this);
  }

  showClue(e) {
    e.currentTarget.remove();

    this.setState({
      clueIsShowing: true
    });

    setInterval(
      () => this.showAnswerLink(),
      1000
    );
  }

  hideClue() {
    this.setState({
      clueIsShowing: false
    });
  }

  showAnswerLink() {
    this.setState({
      showAnswerLink: true
    });
  }

  toggleAnswer() {
    if (!this.state.answerIsShowing) {
      this.setState({
        cardText: this.props.answer
      });
    } else {
      this.setState({
        cardText: this.props.children
      });
    }

    this.setState({
      answerIsShowing: !this.state.answerIsShowing
    });
  }

  render() {
    let valueClass = 'large';
    if(this.props.value.length === 4) {
      valueClass = 'medium';
    }

    let textClass = 'small';
    if(this.state.cardText.length < 20) {
      textClass = 'large';
    }

    return (
      <div className="clue-card">
        <button className={`clue-card__value ${valueClass}`} onClick={this.showClue}><span className="dollar-sign">$</span>{this.props.value}</button>
        <div className={`clue-card__inner ${textClass} ${this.state.clueIsShowing ? 'show' : 'hidden'}`}>
          <div className="clue-card__inner-wrapper">
            <div className="clue-card__clue">{this.state.cardText}</div>
            <button className={`clue-card__answer-link ${this.state.showAnswerLink ? '' : 'hidden'}`} onClick={this.toggleAnswer}>Toggle Answer</button>
            <button className={`clue-card__close-link ${this.state.showAnswerLink ? '' : 'hidden'}`} onClick={this.hideClue}>Close</button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

If you look at the below screen capture, you can see the button is rendered for the first clue, but not for the second clue. This is the expected/desired functionality. I just don't understand why the button is not rendered for the second clue that was already clicked. If I look at the code, I would expect the button to always be rendered.
[image: screen capture]

Comment: please try to inspect and see if it is rendered to the DOM. if it is then we need to check the css of the element or the positioning, zIndex etc. if it is not rendered, that means smth wrong with the react state and need to look further into it.

Comment: @KevinMoeMyintMyat It is not rendered in the DOM, but it is working how it's supposed to; I'm just not understanding how it is working.

Comment: @dikuw so you can see it on element inspect but it not render in DOM ? i dont clearly understand it's working in your comment

Comment: @KhanhLeTran no it is not rendered the DOM, and therefore does not show up on element inspection. I've added a screen capture to clarify. My question is how this is working. If I look at the code, I would expect the button to be rendered every time. I hope this clarifies.

Comment: ok , i'm waiting for screen capture for this case

Comment: @KhanhLeTran attached now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove this:

```
e.currentTarget.remove();
```

This line code will remove the element you target to.

Comment: one more thing , i think the function set interval to change show or not show answer boolean is not necessary, just render show 1 time. Don't use immediate function arbitrary maybe it can be effected to performance after.